# Swift - converting from ConstUnsafePointer<()>

Tags: ios, swift

I'm on beta 3. Consider the following Objective-C line:

```
const uint8_t *reportData = [data bytes];
```

where `data` is a `NSData` object.

**How would this line be re-written in Swift?**

`data.bytes` is of type `ConstUnsafePointer<()>`, and while there's plenty of documentation on how to create a pointer type in Swift, there isn't much info on how to work with them.

**edit:**
To add some context, I'm trying to port Apple's HeartRateMonitor sample code to Swift. This code interacts with BLE heart rate monitors. This code I'm working on translates the data received by the Bluetooth system into an int for use in the UI. The data received from BT is expected to be an array of uints, element 0 is used to check for a flag and element 1 contains the value.

Here's the same Objective-C line in context:

```
const uint8_t *reportData = [data bytes];
uint16_t bpm = 0;

if ((reportData[0] & 0x01) == 0) 
{
    /* uint8 bpm */
    bpm = reportData[1];
}
```

Comment: What is it you want to do with it? What were you doing it in Objective-C? Have you tried just doing that same thing? My experience is that things just go right on working. For example, the individual "bytes" should be accessible using subscripting.

Comment: added some more notes in the original question with context

Comment: And did you try just translating that directly? As I said before, my experience is that subscripting will work just as you expect.

Comment: Without posting each permutation I went through, I'll say I tried several versions attempting a "direct" translation, or using `as` casting, or trying to go through some of the other pointer objects. Some attempts wouldn't compile for type reasons, others would execute but would throw a runtime exception. dankogai's solution looks promising, will need to test when I have my hardware on me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you were looking for was how to convert NSData to an array of UInt8.  Here's how.

```
import Foundation
let path = "/etc/csh.cshrc" // something existent
let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)

var aofb = [UInt8](count:data.length, repeatedValue:0)
data.getBytes(&aofb, length:data.length)

for c in aofb {
    let s = UnicodeScalar(Int(c)).escape(asASCII:true)
    println("\(c):\(s)")
}
```

Comment: Just added some more context to my question - the NSData object received actually represents an array of uints, so trying to convert to string wont work.

Comment: The new example shows how to convert NSData to an array of UInt8.

Answer (score 1):

Just built following code (Note code below works on **Beta 3**, **ConstUnsafePointer<()>** needs to be changed to **COpaquePointer** in order to work on **Beta 2**, please see edit history for more information)

```
var dataPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TestData", ofType: "") // What I have in TestData is "GREETINGS WORLD"
var originalData = NSData(contentsOfFile: dataPath)
var dataLength = originalData.length
println("original data: \(originalData)") // Output original data

// Data to bytes
var reportBytes: ConstUnsafePointer<()> = originalData.bytes
var bytesToString = NSString(bytes: reportBytes, length: dataLength, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println("string from bytes: \(bytesToString)")

// Bytes to data
var bytesToData = NSData(bytes: reportBytes, length: dataLength)
println("data from bytes: \(bytesToData)")
```

Console log

```
original data: <47524545 54494e47 5320574f 524c44>
string from bytes: GREETINGS WORLD
data from bytes: <47524545 54494e47 5320574f 524c44>
```

Also found this may help

```
ConstUnsafePointer<T>

/// This type stores a pointer to an object of type T. It provides no
/// automated memory management, and therefore the user must take care
/// to allocate and free memory appropriately.
```

Hope this shed light.

Comment: Just added some more context to my question - the NSData object received actually represents an array of uints, so trying to convert to string wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at handling bluetooth heart rate monitors in Swift now I found the simplest way to get the NSData byte values to UInt8 format:

```
let bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)

if bytes[0] & 0x01 == 0 {
    NSLog("BPM \(bytes[1]")
}
```