# What data type should I use when converting a byte array from Swift to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

I have a project where I write the production code in Swift and my unit tests in Objective-C (because I'm using OCMock I write my tests in Objective-C).

What I'm trying to do is to write a `Buffer` object where the `writeBytes` method takes a `Byte` array and a length, like this:

```
func writeBytes(data: [Byte], length: Int)
```

In my unit test target I want to test this method, but the problem is that it won't convert this method to Objective-C.
By looking in my `-Swift.h` file I see the following:

```
@interface Buffer : Object
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger capacity;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger size;
- (instancetype)initWithCapacity:(NSInteger)capacity OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)reset;
- (NSInteger)size;
- (BOOL)isFilled;
- (BOOL)isEmpty;
@end
```

As you can see the `writeBytes` method is missing. I've tried different data types to see if it appears: `UInt8`, `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`, but none of them work.

For the sake of debugging I tried using a `String` array and that gets converted to Objective-C without any problems.

What data type should I use for my `Byte` array to make the `writeBytes` method available in Objective-C?

Comment: Are you sure you're recompiling each time?

Comment: Yes, since it is working with String arrays I know the file gets updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift type `[Byte]` is not representable in Objective-C, but you can work with
a *pointer* to the bytes:

```
func writeBytes(data: ConstUnsafePointer<Byte>, length: Int) { ... }

var data : [Byte] = [1, 2, 3]
writeBytes(data, length: data.count)
```

This mapped to Objective-C as

```
- (void)writeBytes:(Byte const *)data length:(NSInteger)length;
```

so that you can call it like

```
Byte data[] = {1, 2, 3};
[buffer writeBytes:data length:3];
```

Comment: Ah, nice! This works, thank you! I only tested it with [UnsafePointer<Byte>] and not as you suggested.

Comment: @Downvoter: It would be helpful to know what is wrong about this answer, so that I can fix it if necessary ...

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  You can create one from an array of `[UInt8]` in Swift as:

```
import Foundation
var u8s = [UInt8]()
// ...
var data = NSData(bytes:&u8s, length:u8s.count)
```

FYI this is the opposite of [Swift - converting from ConstUnsafePointer<()>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688507/swift-converting-from-constunsafepointer/24690522#24690522) where the questioner was looking for the way to convert NSData to `[UInt8]`.